Link keyvault with variable group using REST API
I am trying to execute REST API to link keyvault with variable group, when I execute below REST API command as it is executing but when I go to variable group the secrets are not saving and showing at the top

Value cannot be null. Parameter name: variableGroupParameters

Even when I want to update new secret, it is throwing the same error. Does anyone know the solution?
curl -X POST \
  -u :PAT_TOKEN \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d @kv_payload.json \
  "https://dev.azure.com/{org_name}/{project_name}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

Payload
{
    "name": "variablegroupname",
    "type": "AzureKeyVault",
    "providerData": {
        "serviceEndpointId": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "vault": "keyvaultname"
    },
    "variables": {
        "storage-name": {
            "value": "null",
            "isSecret": true,
            "contentType": "",
            "enabled": true
        },
        "my-password": {
            "value": "null",
            "isSecret": true,
            "contentType": "",
            "enabled": true
        }
    },
    "description": "Keyvault secrets managed by automated script"
}


You can link key vault to a variable group using below Rest API and request body.
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=7.2-preview.2

Request body should be in below format-
{
  "name": "MyVariableGroupForSecrets",
  "description": "variable group created for Key vault",
  "Type": "AzureKeyVault",
  "ProviderData": {
    "serviceEndpointId": "68d1****da6",
    "vault": "afreeenkvv"
  },
  "variables": {
    "test": {
      "value": "",
      "isSecret": true,
      "contentType": "",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "variableGroupProjectReferences": [
    {
      "name": "MyVariableGroupForSecrets",
      "description": "variable group created for Key vault",
      "projectReference": {
        "id": "2cfd*****c5",
        "name": "{projectName}"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I am able to create the variable group.



I have also tried using the rest api, It works, My previous method failed because I used the type of vsts, but actually AzureKeyVault, Json body shows below:
{
  "type": "AzureKeyVault",
  "providerData": {
    "serviceEndpointId": "xxxx",
    "vault": "wb-xxxx-test-once"
  },
  "name": "wbvgkv",
  "variableGroupProjectReferences": [
    {
      "projectReference": {
        "name": "xxxx"
      },
      "name": "wbvgkv"
    }
  ],
  "variables": {
    "wbsecretname": {
      "enable": true,
      "isSecret": true
    }
  },
  "description": "variable group from script auto created"
}

You can use a pipeline yaml to verify your secret from vg
variables:
- group: wbvgkv

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
 
      Write-Output "showing secret type value from keyvault key wbsecretname: $(wbsecretname)"

      "secret string is: $(wbsecretname)" | Out-File -FilePath "wb.txt" -Append

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\wb.txt
    artifactName: drop

The secret value will explicitly save in the Drop


